# Applescript: Curl command was working, now I get a missing token error

Tags: shell, curl, applescript

I had the following Applescript code that was previously working, but now I get the error: Expected “given”, “in”, “of”, expression, “with”, “without”, other parameter name, etc. but found unknown token. Is it some kind of permissions issue?

`do shell script 'curl -L -o "/Users/myUserName/Desktop/newimagename.jpg" "https://somewebsite.com/files/gallery/1676041915.jpg"'`

I was expecting the image to be downloaded to my desktop with its new name. I have confirmed the website url to the jpg is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problems with quotes here. The outer quotes are for the **do shell script** command of the AppleScript language (more precisely, of its Standard additions) and they must be **double (")**. And the **single quotes (')** are for shell commands, which is the **curl** command too.

That is, you need to swap them:

```
do shell script "curl -L -o '/Users/myUserName/Desktop/newimagename.jpg' 'https://somewebsite.com/files/gallery/1676041915.jpg'"
```

Other, and the better choice is using **quoted form of** for the provided paths.

```
set outputPath to "/Users/myUserName/Desktop/newimagename.jpg"
set sourceURL to "https://somewebsite.com/files/gallery/1676041915.jpg"

do shell script "curl -L -o " & quoted form of outputPath & space & quoted form of sourceURL
```